# Invertible (isometric) sections of certain hom bundles over sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Assume  that we  have  a  vector  bundle $E$ over  $S^n$.

> Is  there  a  continuous  family of invertible linear  maps  $T_x:E_x \to  E_{-x}$?

Here  continuity has  the  obvious  meaning as soon as  we  have  trivialization for  the  bundle  around $x$ and  $-x$

There is an obvious affirmative answer for the non orientable line bundle over $S^1$,  for the tangent bundle of $S^n$ and  for  the  $2$  dimensional real vector  bundle $E \to S^2 \simeq \mathbb{C}P^1$ where  $E$ is the  tautological  complex line  bundle  over  $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

If the  answer is  yes, what  about  if  we  consider  $E$  as  a  Riemannian  bundle  and  we  require that every  $T_x$  be an  isometric  linear  map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such family of *complex* linear maps for the tautological bundle on $\mathbb CP^1$. The antipodal map is orientation reversing, hence the first Chern class changes its sign. The same argument should work for the positive complex spinor bundle on any even-dimensional sphere.

The same argument also works for a real vector bundle on $S^{4k}$ with non-vanishing $k$-th Pontryagin class. Probably again the positive real spinor bundle is an example.

On the other hand, the answer to the second question is "yes" because $O(r)$ or $U(r)$  is a deformation retract of $GL(r,\mathbb R)$ or $GL(r,\mathbb C)$, respectively.

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  answer.  I  consider the  tautological  bundle  as  a  real  2  dimensional  bundle  over  S^2. The  antipodal  map 
 on  $S^2 \simeq \mathbb{C}P^1$, I think,  is read  as  the  map  $[z,w] \mapsto  [-w,z]$. So  the  desired  linear  map  is  $([z,w],(x,y)) \mapsto  {[-w,z],(-y,x})$.  So  am  I  mistaken to think that  the  map exist  for  $S^2$  with  two  dimensional  real  vector  bundle  $E=$ complex  line    tautological  bundle?

Comment: My  apology  for  my  mistake  in previous  comment. The  antipodal  map  has  no  fixed point  but  my  representaion  has  fixed point  on  CP^1.  But  what  is  representaion of  the  antipodal  map  on $S^2$ in terms  of  coordinate  of  $\mathbb{C}P^2$?

Comment: I think it is $(z:w)\mapsto(-\bar w:\bar z)$.

Comment: Ah  Yes Thank  you.  So  your  answer says that  as  complex  bundle  there  are  no  such  complex  linear  maps $T_x$ yes?

Comment: Accoring  to the  first  line  of your  answer  I realize that   the  answer to  my  question is  positive  iff  and  oly  if  $f*(E) \simeq  E$ where  $f$  is  the  antipodal  map.  But  the  complex  line  bundle $0(-1)$  pull  back  to $O(1)$, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if a real vector bundle of rank $k$ over $S^n$ is isomorphic to its antipodal image.
If $n$ is odd, the answer is always yes because the antipodal map is homotopic to the identity of $S^n$.
If $k=2$, the answer is easily seen to be yes, because the oriented $2$-bundles are classified by an integer, the Euler class.
If $n$ is even, such a real vector bundle amounts to a free homotopy class of continuous maps $S^n\to BO(k)$. i.e. to a pair of elements $\alpha, \bar\alpha$ of the homotopy group
$\pi_n(BSO(k))$, where $BSO(k)$ is the Grassmannian space of the oriented $k$-planes in $R^\infty$, and where $\bar\alpha$ is the image of $\alpha$ by an orientation-reversing isometry. One has $\pi_n(BSO(k))\cong\pi_{n-1}(SO(k))$. Your question amounts to ask that $\alpha=\alpha^{-1}$ or $\alpha=\bar\alpha^{-1}$. I believe that the second always holds, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is $\alpha^{-1}$ your notation for the inverse in $\pi_n(-)$? Note that the antipodal map has degree $(-1)^{n+1}$. So $\bar\alpha=\alpha^{(-1)^{n+1}}$ by Hopf's theorem of self maps of $S^n$.

Comment: @Sebastian Goette Yes, $\alpha^{-1}$ denotes the inverse in $\pi_n(-)$, and as you mention, for $n$ even, this is the same as $\alpha$ composed at the source by the antipodal map. But $\bar\alpha$ denotes something else: $\alpha$ being the homotopy class of a map $f:S^n\to SO(k)$, by $\bar\alpha$ I mean the class of $\sigma\circ f$, where $\sigma:SO(k)\to SO(k)$ is the conjugation by an element of $O(k)\setminus SO(k)$.

Comment: I see, so $\bar\alpha$ is the same bundle, but with opposite orientation? In my answer I named the Pontryagin class as an obstruction. Note that $\alpha$ and $\bar\alpha$ have the same Pontryagin classes, only the Euler class changes sign (and therefore does not give an obstruction). To see that the positive and the negative spinor bundles $S^\pm$ in dimension $4k$ have opposite nontrivial $p_k$, note that the Chern character is a multiple of $p_k$. Then apply the index theorem to the Dirac operator twisted by $S^+$ and $S^-$.

Comment: @Sebastian Goette Thank you Sebastian, so, this gives examples where $\alpha^{-1}\neq \alpha$ nor $\bar\alpha$, and where the answer to Ali's question is negative.

Comment: @GaelMeigniez  Thank  you  again for  your  interesting  answer. I am  sorry that  I  can not  accept  two  answers simultaneously.