# Continuous orthogonal preserving maps between projective space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

> Is there  a  continuous map $f:\mathbb{C}P^n \to \mathbb{C}P^m$, for  some $n>m$
>   which preserve orthogonality?Namely $x\perp y \implies f(x) \perp f(y) $?
>
> If yes, are there two non homotopic  maps with this  property?

For  a  related post see this  question

[Continuous maps $f:S^n \to \mathbb{C}P^m$ with $f(x)\perp f(-x) $](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278828/continuous-maps-fsn-to-mathbbcpm-with-fx-perp-f-x)

Comment: What is orthogonality in $\mathbb{CP}^n$?

Comment: @abx  Orthogonality of  lines with respect to the  standard inner product  of  $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose such a map exists, let $x\in\mathbb{C}^n-\{0\}$, we denote by $[x]$ its class in $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Let $H_x$ be the orthogonal of $x$, $f([H_x])$ is orthogonal to $f(x)$, so $f$ induces a map $f_1:\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{m-1}$ which has the same property, recursively, you obtain a map $f_m:\mathbb{C}P^{n-m}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^0$ with the same property, and this is impossible.

Comment: What is  $H_x$? is it  a  line?How  do you  choose it, continuously?

Comment: It is the orthogonal hyperplane to $x$. I fix an $x$, no need to choose $H_x$ continuously.

Comment: So  what  does it mean $f([H_x])$? f is  defined  on the projective space not on grassmanian.

Comment: It is the image of $f$ restricted to the projective hyperplane $[H_x]$.

Comment: Or more directly: just choose $n+1$ mutually orthogonal lines in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, and apply $f$ to obtain $n+1$ mutually orthogonal lines in $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$, which is impossible.

Comment: @NeilStrickland (and @Tsemo)  My  apology for  my bad and trivial question. it is fair that the  question will be voted to closed. thanks  for help of you.

Comment: @NeilStrickland(and @Tsemo))  what  can be  said about the  homotopy  class of  any such map when n=m). For  n=m=1, the  map can not  be  null homotopic but what about  higher values  of  n=m). What can think to the same  question for n<m.

Comment: @AliTaghavi if $n<m$, then the natural inclusion has the property stated in the question.